# Trouble installing Ubuntu on Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 P3110

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Everytime i try to install it, it all works but it boots up into a black screen

Comment: Can you be more specific on your download sources? Does adb shell work? Is there anything interesting show by running adb logcat?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: That is from back in April. *At very least, you need to be trying to install an older non-flipped, Raring version.* Read the rest of the thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2166921&page=29